# How does the javadoc know which method each documentation comment is for?

Tags: java, comments, javadoc

In the following code:

```
public class Rectangle {
    private double length;
    private double width;

    /**
     * The setLength method stores a value in the
     * length field.
     * @param len The value to store in length.
     * 
     */

    public void setLength(double len){
        length  = len;
    }
```

How does the `javadoc` associate my comment with the `setLength` method? Is it simply because the comment came right before the method declaration?

Comment: You can just try it... Write 2 JavaDoc comments without a method in between, write a method below, then have a look if one is taken and if yes, which one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed simply because the comment comes right before the method declaration.

Although it is not explicitly stated as far as I can see, it follows from the description of how the JavaDoc Tool works, see [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html)

Specifically, the section about [Source Files](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#sourcefiles):

> The Javadoc tool can generate output originating from four different
>   types of "source" files:
>
> - Source code files for Java classes (.java) - these contain class, interface, field, constructor and method comments.
> - [...]

and

> A doc comment is written in HTML and must precede a class, field, constructor or method declaration.